# How To Make Multi Language Web and set the value into Resource.resx from database

Tags: asp.net, resourcedictionary

I want to translate my Web Page Into Different language , And the value of the word are in the data-base ,

How to Set the resource value from data-base table , every value in different table

Answer (score 1):

If i get it right, you want to **populate** your resources files **dynamically** from your `DataBase`. You can achieve that by creating the `.resx` files in your project, the next step would be **add/update** its content using the code below:

```
public static void AddOrUpdateResource(string key, string value)
        {
            var path = @"YourResourceFilePath.resx";
            var resx = new List<DictionaryEntry>();
            using (var reader = new ResXResourceReader(path))
            {
                resx = reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToList();
                var existingResource = resx.Where(r => r.Key.ToString() == key).FirstOrDefault();
                if (existingResource.Key == null && existingResource.Value == null) // NEW!
                {
                    resx.Add(new DictionaryEntry() { Key = key, Value = value });
                }
                else // MODIFIED RESOURCE!
                {
                    var modifiedResx = new DictionaryEntry() { Key = existingResource.Key, Value = value };
                    resx.Remove(existingResource);  // REMOVING RESOURCE!
                    resx.Add(modifiedResx);  // AND THEN ADDING RESOURCE!
                }
            }
            using (var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(path))
            {
                resx.ForEach(r =>
                {
                    // Again Adding all resource to generate with final items
                    writer.AddResource(r.Key.ToString(), r.Value.ToString());
                });
                writer.Generate();
            }
        }
```

Then you can call this method and pass the key-value from your `DataBase`.

Comment: I did it from the data-base ,it would take some time but its a lot of data